# Problems with implementing a simple deck of cards. Undefined reference to Class::Constructor, Class::Destructor

Tags: c++

Hey guys I'm trying to implement a deck of cards in C++. and it's starting to drive me mad.

Please could you have a look at my code and point out any of the mistakes and how to change them?

ATM I'm getting:

in test.cpp undefined reference to Deck::~Deck()

in deck.cpp undefined reference to Card::Card()

in deck.cpp undefined reference to Card::~Card()

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum cardRank { c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, J, Q, K, A };
enum cardSuit { S, H, D, C };

class Card{
private:
    int rank;
    int suit;
public:
    Card();
    Card(int r, int s);
    ~Card();

    int getRank();

    int getSuit();

    void printCard();

};


#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"

    Card::Card(int r, int s): rank(r), suit(s) {}

    int Card::getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    int Card::getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    void Card::printCard() {
        string r;
        string s;
        switch(rank) {
            case 0:
                r = '2';
                break;
            case 1:
                r = '3';
                break;
            case 2:
                r = '4';
                break;
            case 3:
                r = '5';
                break;
            case 4:
                r = '6';
                break;
            case 5:
                r = '7';
                break;
            case 6:
                r = '8';
                break;
            case 7:
                r = '9';
                break;
            case 8:
                r = "10";
                break;
            case 9:
                r = 'J';
                break;
            case 10:
                r = 'Q';
                break;
            case 11:
                r = 'K';
                break;
            case 12:
                r = 'A';
                break;
        }
        switch(suit) {
            case 0:
                s = 'S';
                break;
            case 1:
                s = 'H';
                break;
            case 2:
                s = 'D';
                break;
            case 3:
                s = 'C';
                break;
        }
        cout << '(' << r << ", " << s << ")";
    }
```

Deck.h

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H
#include "Card.h"
#include "random/randomc.h"
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

class Deck{
private:
    CRandomMersenne random;
    Card deck[51];
    bool dealt[51];
public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();

    Card * deal();

};

#endif
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

    Deck::Deck() : random((int)time(0)){
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i ++) {
            deck[i] = Card(i % 13, i % 4 );
            dealt[i] = false;
        }
    }
    /*
    Deck::~Deck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            delete deck[i];
        }
    }
*/
    Card * Deck::deal() {
        int card;
        do {        
            card = random.IRandom(0,51);
        } while(dealt[card] == true);
        dealt[card] = true;
        return &deck[card];
    }
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deck.h"
using namespace std;

int main (){
    Deck * d = new Deck();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ){
        Card * dealt = d->deal();
        dealt->printCard();
        cout << "     ";
    }
    delete d;

}
```

Comment: Your error message says what methods aren't implemented, why won't you implement them?

Comment: It could be because you declare those functions in the classes in the header files, but you do not define (implement) them in the source files. Either remove the declarations in the header files, or implement them in your source files.

Answer (score 1):

You've *declared* the destructors for your classes in their respective header files, but you haven't *defined* them in the implementation/source files.

Well, you defined one of them (`~Deck`), but then you commented it out.

The compiler is telling you that it's found the declaration and is trying to call the destructor in response to your call to `delete`, but it can't because its implementation has never been defined anywhere.

The fix is simple: **implement your destructors**, even if they're just empty methods that do nothing.

The larger lesson is to pay closer attention to the error messages that your compiler gives you. They're not nearly as hard to read as you might have thought, and most importantly, they tell you how to fix your code so that it will compile!

Comment: thanks a lot, for some reason I thought that declaring it, would mean that I want C++ to implicitly implement the destructor for me.

Comment: @user1066113: Nope, the implicit implementation happens when you *don't* declare it.

Answer (score 0):

To Card.cpp add:

```
Card::~Card(){
// Actions which shall be done when the object is deleted
}
Card::Card(){
// Actions which shall be done when the object is created without any parameters
}
```

and to Deck.cpp add:

```
Deck::~Deck(){
// Actions which shall be done when the object is deleted
}
```

You declared the destructors of the objects but you didn't implement then. E.g. when you call

> delete d

in your main program it expects a defined destructor ( since you added it to the header ) but doesn't find one since you didn't implement it.

Hope I could help.

Best Regards